# How to make the text of 2 UILabels match?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working on an Xcode project and am wondering how to make 2 labels have the exact same text even when 1 label changes.

Ex. @"Your reaction time was 421 milliseconds."
Ex. @"Your reaction time was 131 milliseconds."

So they match exactly. I was thinking something like

text.label = text.label2 but I think I'm missing something.

The labels are on different views.

Comment: What do you mean by "matching"?

Comment: I mean the exact same, on one screen it will say for ex 4 so the other label changes to 4

Answer (score 1):

If you want the second label to always change to reflect the changes to the first label, you'll have to use an observer. For example:

1. Add the second view controller as an observer of the first label:

   ```
   [label1 addObserver: secondViewController forKeyPath: @"text" options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context: nil];
   ```
2. The second view controller should have a method like this, which will set the text of the second label:

   ```
   - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                 ofObject:(id)object 
                   change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                  context:(void *)context
   {
       label2.text = [change valueForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, it's so kind of people! :)

Comment: Please help, in what view controller and file do I put the first piece of code in. Thanks.

Comment: That would be in an init or load method of the same controller that has the observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context method

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
[label setText:label2.text];
```

more likely.

Comment: Thank you will this work if it's in different views because it is not right now.

Comment: Do you mean in different viewcontrollers? You would have to pass the value from one controller to another, or store it in your delegate.